# When to pass a parameter as a constructor parameter or as a method parameter

Tags: java, spring, testing, spock

I currently have this class that uses a Service class in a class method. Currently I am creating an instance of the service class in my method as shown below. The question I am wondering is that when it comes to testing, I am using spock and it seems to be difficult to test when a new instance of a class is being created in the method rather than being passed in as a constructor parameter for dependency injection. I am wondering would passing in an instance of Service class into Handler as a constructor parameter be the correct way of doing this? Thanks

```
public class Handler{
   private Service service;

    public Handler(){}

public void someMethod(ObjectNeededForService object){
   service = new Service(object);
}
}
```

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, because it will attract opinionated answer. If you have a concrete problem, you need to describe it. You tagged the question with _spock_ and also mention Spock testing, but where is your Spock test? Please be advised to learn how to ask good questions by providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky question and you'll find different answers for that.
If I understand correctly, you are basically asking if constructor injection is better than setter injection or vice versa, correct?

Obviously constructor injection is neat when you have a limited amount of fields in your class. Constructors with 20 args are not very readable and should definitely be avoided. In that case you would have to use setter injection and call the setters for the individual fields one by one.

But maybe if you have a class with so many fields that need injecting, it would be good to refactor and get your dependencies down to a smaller amount.

Personally I prefer construtor injection but there are arguments against it.

Comment: Yes setter injection is making it difficult for me to test it as it will use the new instance of the class instead of the Mock one I created for it. Whereas with constructor I can pass in the Mock instance of the class and it will use that. One main benefit of constructor injection I guess is that it is easier to test due to the use of Mocks? But yes, thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm not sure you need the injection on mocked classes. The class that you are testing should not contain any mocks or the test is not very useful. If you mock other classes you can just pass them in through the constructor or through the setter. Both would work.

Comment: @DonalDraper, your comment is unclear. Why would it make any difference whether you use constructor or setter injection? The effect is the same. You can pass a mock via constructor or setter.

Comment: @geanakuch, we cannot know if mocks would be helpful in order to test the example class, because clearly the example is incomplete insofar as we do not see what the class does with the `Service` after it was constructed. We can only speculate that it might be calling methods upon it, yielding some interaction with other components like back-end services, and the user wants to avoid that in order to test `Handler` in isolation. In that case, an injectable mock, maybe with some method stubs, would in fact be very helpful.